# MySQL query for 3 consecutive integers between records

Tags: mysql

Given a table where each record has a year integer value, how do I query to see if there are 3 or more consecutive years?

```
| id | year |
+----+------+
| 1  | 1990 |
| 1  | 1991 |
| 1  | 1992 |
| 2  | 1973 |
| 3  | 1993 |
| 3  | 1994 |
| 3  | 1995 |
| 3  | 1996 |
```

Given the above table, the resulting records returned by the query would be:

```
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
| 3  |
```

The query would return ids 1 and 3 since those two records contain have consecutive years. How would I write such a query?

Comment: Wrong!  Id #1 has only 2 consecutive years; 1992 is missing.  Please restate the question.

Comment: Oops, there you have it.

Comment: Would this count?  90,91,93,94?  (I suspect not.)  Or this?  90,91,93,94,85?  (I suspect so.)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
t.id
FROM tablename t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM tablename x
    WHERE x.id = t.id
    AND x.year = t.year+1
)
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM tablename x
    WHERE x.id = t.id
    AND x.year = t.year-1
)
```

Comment: Where's the check against "3"?

Comment: @RickJames There are three consecutive years in a row if for a given year there exists a year before and a year after that given year, for the same id. Seems valid to me, but it is late for me right now.